# Appending data to csv file & lebelling in R

Tags: r

I'm appending data in csv file and assigning column names but column names are not appearing appropriately. I have given the code and output below.

```
    setwd("C:Users/Data")
    write.csv(c(), "Summary.csv")

    L <- 10:15
    T <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6) 
    df1 <- data.frame(L, T)
    names(df1) <- c("L", "T")

    for(i in 1:dim(df1)[1]){

        temp_d1 <- df1[i, ]

             if (i == 1){
  write.table(temp_d1, file="Summary.csv", append=TRUE, col.names = TRUE,sep = ',')
  }else{

    write.table(temp_d1, file="Summary.csv", append=TRUE, col.names = FALSE,sep = ',')

             }

}
```

Below is the output of Summary.csv file. I dont understand why the first additional column 1:6 is appearing in the csv. Ideally label "L" should be for column 10:15 and "T" for 0.1:0.6 but it's not as I expect. Please advice to label correctly.

```
L   T   
1   10  0.1
2   11  0.2
3   12  0.3
4   13  0.4
5   14  0.5
6   15  0.6
```

Comment: `row.names=FALSE` should do it

Answer (score 0):

By default, `write.table` will add row names or numbers to each line.  To stop this, add an argument `row.names = FALSE` to your `write.table` statements.